# Smartyでjson_decodeして要素数を取得する方法

Tags: smarty

Smarty で JSON データを `json_decode` で配列にしてその要素数を取得しようとしています。

想定する JSON データは以下の通りです。

```php
$json_member = '
    [
      {"userid":"0","name":"Taro Yamada","email":"taro@xxx.com"},
      {"userid":"1","name":"Jiro Yamada","email":"jiro@xxx.com"},
      {"userid":"2","name":"Saburoh Yamada","email":"saburoh@xxx.com"},
                               :
    ]';
```

Smarty で以下のコードで実行すると「0 名」になります。

```php
{ $json_member|@json_decode|@count|cat:' 名' }
```

ググってみていろいろと試しているのですが、あるべき出力になりません。
もしご存知でしたらご教授のほどおねがいいたします。

Comment: `$json_member` を php のコード側で `json_decode` して成功しますか？
そこで失敗しているように思います。

Comment: お返事が遅くなり申し訳御座いません。

確認したところ、json_decodeでこけていました。
ありがとうございました。